# The high score system for my unity program does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set up a high score system but the high score does not change at all even though the scoring system works. How do i make the high score text update as well?

I have been messing around with the code trying to get it to work but it has been to no avail.

```
public Transform player;
public Text scoreText;
public Text highScore;


void start() => highScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score", 0).ToString();

// Update is called once per frame
public void Update()
{
    scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString("0");
    int scoreTextNumber = int.Parse(scoreText.text);

    if (scoreTextNumber > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score", 0))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("High Score", scoreTextNumber);
        highScore.text = scoreTextNumber.ToString();
    }

}
```

The high score is meant to update as the score updates but it doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that `player.position.z` is a float. And if you [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) a string representing a float the tryparse fails.

In your specific case you do not need Parse at all and you may use `player.position.z` directly (casting it to int first). It is also much better for performance since you're doing it in Update.

Also the `start` method should be capitalized to `Start()`.

```
public Transform player;
public Text scoreText;
public Text highScore;


void Start() => highScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score", 0).ToString();

// Update is called once per frame
public void Update()
{
    int score = (int) player.position.z;
    scoreText.text = score.ToString("0");

    if (score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score", 0))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("High Score", score);
        highScore.text = score.ToString();
    }    
}
```